# Как экранировать { в php строке?

Tags: php

```
$mailbox = "{$host:993/imap/ssl}";
```

Код не работает

```
$mailbox = "\{$host:993/imap/ssl}";
```

\ - попадает в переменную

```
$mailbox = "{imap.mail.ru:993/imap/ssl}";
```

Работает как надо

Comment: `"{$host}:993/imap/ssl";`

Comment: @Эдуард это шутка такая?

Answer (score 1):

Если переменную нужно вывести, просто добавьте ещё пару фигурных скобок:

```
echo  "{{$host}:993/imap/ssl}"; // {imap.mail.ru:993/imap/ssl}
```

---

Если переменную выводить не нужно:

Экранировать нужно не скобки, а признак переменной:

```
echo  "{\$host:993/imap/ssl}"; // {$host:993/imap/ssl}
```

По хорошему, проще использовать литерал без поддержки управляющих последовательностей:

```
echo  '{$host:993/imap/ssl}'; // {$host:993/imap/ssl}
```

Comment: дак переменную то надо вывести, только фигурные скобки по краям оставить. тут просто переменную надо в еще пару скобок обернуть.

Comment: хотя честно сказать, не совсем понятно что надо :D

Comment: всё тут очевидно. Надо вывести и переменную и фигурные скобки. так что первый вариант подходит. либо конкатенация

Comment: Очевидность - понятие относительное

Answer (score 0):

```
$mailbox = '{'.$host.':993/imap/ssl}';
```